# Show Grid in XtraTreeList on a specified Node

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid, xtratreelist

How do I show XtraGrid  Control in XtraTreeList on specific Node  during TreeBuilding ?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to show an XtraGrid in a TreeList node.  Currently, this can be done in ASP.NET only...